# Best practices for adding a Twitter view as an app-support mechanism?

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm looking into adding a simple Twitter view into my apps, mainly for support and a bit of community.  What would be best practices for integrating Twitter into an app when it strictly serves a supporting role (not a starring role)?  I haven't seen other apps do this yet, but I'll humbly assume that I'm not the first to try this.

Motivation: From my perspective, communicating with my customers about support issues, app ideas, and general announcements, is pretty tough.  I tried Ning.com, getsatisfaction.com, e-mail, etc., but they were too disconnected from my app.  Actually, e-mail works fairly well for one-on-one support, but not general communications.  Now, some of my apps have their own twitter accounts, which I quite like, but they are still quite disconnected from the app experience.  I would like my users to see, from within the app, recent tweets related to that app and, if the real twitter app is installed, to then go over to the real Twitter app to post their own tweets.  They could see bug-work-arounds, use cases, related links, etc.  It would be just awesome.

Weaselly follow-up question: What would be a smart implementation approach?  MGTwitter seems maybe overkill.  Maybe throwing the twitter html widget into a webview?